# Swift barcode scanning only works in the dark

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I'm building a barcode scanning app and it works great most of the time.  One problem I'm having is one item will refuse to scan under normal most lighter lighting conditions but will scan when slightly dark.

My question is, how can I get the camera to think filter things to be darker than they are to get this item to scan?  Are there any customizable settings that are typically used in circumstances such as this?

Edit:  The shift is very noticeable when it goes from more to less ambient light and the barcode instantly scans.

Edit 2:  I know of exposure but the docs by apple and examples on github don't do a great job of explaining the effects of changing particular values in `captureDevice?.setExposureModeCustom` in the context my issue.  If anyone has a link that points to good readings the are useful in relation to my issue.  But telling me to "google avfoundation expusre" is not helpful.

Comment: Presumably you're using the AVFoundation camera. You have control over the exposure.

Comment: Can you go into any more detail?